# Google App Scripts Array not writing to sheet as expected

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Using Google app scripts I am trying to consolidate the data from a number of google sheets into a single sheet.  To do this I am saving the values of each sheet to an array using push. The array appears to be saving the data correctly however when writing it out something is not working right.  It appears to be the length function being used to write out the array.

Here is the array values from the log file:

```
[[[Text 1, Text 2, Gallon, 17.12, Tier 2 Generic Chem, 1.0, 125.0, 280.0, 120.0, , 95.0, 55.0, , , , 150.0, , 826.0, 14141.12, , , ], [Text 3, Text 4, Gallon, 16.11, Tier 2 Generic Chem, , , 270.0, , , , , , , , , , 270.0, 4349.7, , , ]]]
```

the issue seems to be with the following code probably since there are 3 [ int he array above but  I am not sure how to fix it so it references the correct elements.

```
consol_sheet.getRange(2,1,finalvalues2.length,finalvalues2[0].length).setValues(finalvalues2);
```

Desired values:

`finalvalues2.length = 2` and `finalvalues2[0].length = 21`

Full Code:

```
function getLastDataRow(sheet) {
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var range = sheet.getRange("B" + lastRow);
  if (range.getValue() !== "") {
    return lastRow;
  } else {
    return range.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP).getRow();
  }              
}

function iterateSheets2() 
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var folder=DriveApp.getFolderById('1k6ja-fmgxiVSY_Kw3kuwLTXWIkQCmTmD');//replace id with actual id of folder
  var files=folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
  var consol_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1HpQYDC8eRVLbEzOOGKsqHE6RGBKTE-6sqx5kTf8-TzM').getActiveSheet();
  consol_sheet.clear()
  var final_values = [];
  var finalvalues2 = [];
while(files.hasNext())
     {
      var file=files.next();
       Logger.log(file.getName());  
            
       var ts=SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId());  //file.getId()            
       var allShts = ts.getSheetByName('FY20')                    
       var lr = getLastDataRow(allShts)       
       var consol_values = allShts.getRange(9,1,lr-8,22).getValues();                   
       finalvalues2.push(consol_values[0]) 
       Logger.log(finalvalues2)
                   
          
     }
   // consol_sheet.getRange(2,1,consol_values.length,consol_values[0].length).setValues(consol_values);
  consol_sheet.getRange(2,1,finalvalues2.length,finalvalues2[0].length).setValues(finalvalues2);
```

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets

Comment: `finalvalues2.push(consol_values[0])` you're only pushing the first row.

Comment: sorry, I was messing with the code between my original post and when I posted code and forgot to get rid of the [0].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Your array is 3-D, to set values into a spreadsheet you need a 2-D value range

Not sure how you obtained this array, but you can convert it to 2-D with

`finalvalues2 = finalvalues2[0];`

Subsequently your request to set values into the sheet should work as intended.

UPDATE

If your 3D array has more than one 2-D entries, an elegant way to convert it would be with a combination of [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) and [apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

`finalvalues2 = [].concat.apply([],finalvalues2);`

Comment: Turns out that only worked when I had 1 file in the folder, when added a second I get error.     Exception: The parameters (number[]) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues. (line 37, file "test")

Comment: I just saw your code, so are you using `finalvalues2.push(consol_values[0])` or `finalvalues2.push(consol_values)`?

Comment: In case it is the latter you are attempting to perform - see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks again, I would have never figured that out on my own.